# Can I roll my HSA into my 401K?

Tags: united-states, 401k, hsa

I am 66 years old and enrolled into Medicare Part A.  I am no longer eligible to contribute to my company's HDHC (HSA type) healthcare plan.  Can I roll my current HSA into my 401K?

Answer (score 4):

Even if you could, which I don't think you can, I'm not sure why you would want to.  Even if you can no longer contribute in to the account, the account is yours and the funds in the account can still be spent on qualified expenses.  Qualified HSA expenses span a very wide range of things from your normal prescription drug costs to nursing home costs and long term care premiums.

Comment: I agree. HSA disbursements aren't taxable as long as they're spent on qualified medical expenses. 401(k) disbursements are taxable no matter what you spend it on. IMO it's the smart move to keep those funds in the HSA. Don't spend the tax!

Answer (score 4):

Based on my research and understanding, no - there is no IRS-approved way to transfer HSA funds into a 401k or IRA.  (Note that there are ways to transfer funds from an IRA to a HSA, but that doesn't help you.)

That said, there are still a few options.  First, since you're 66 years old, you can make distributions from the HSA for any purpose, and those distributions are subject only to ordinary income tax rates.  (That is, the 20% withdrawal penalty does not apply.)  So in that regard, you can consider your HSA much like an extension of your 401k plan.  In addition, withdrawals for qualified medical expenses can be made without incurring any tax penalty.  Despite the fact that you are on Medicare-A, you are still likely to have some qualified medical expenses to pay, and you can use your HSA to pay them.  According to IRS Pub #969, this includes medical and dental expenses for yourself, your spouse, and your dependents (but not non-prescription medicines), and (because you are over 65) insurance premiums such as for Medicare for yourself (and also your spouse, if over 65).

Finally, you may be able to take the distribution from your HSA, pay the ordinary income tax, and then deposit the remainder into your 401k.  Since unlike an IRA you cannot simply write a check to your 401k, it becomes trickier to get that money into the account - but you should be able to increase your payroll deferral temporarily and make up the difference from the funds you withdrew from the HSA.

With that said, I do not recommend this approach.  The funds in an HSA are more generic and more flexible than those in the 401k, particularly now that you've reached the age where the penalty no longer applies.  Since you are very likely to incur admissible health care expenses in the next 5-10 years, leave the money where it is and use it to pay for those expenses as they come due.  This comes at the cost of a small additional amount of paperwork to manage, but that should be offset by the income tax savings, especially since you say you are still working.

[IRS Publication 969 (2015) HSAs And Other Tax-Favored Health Plans](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969/ar02.html#en_US_2015_publink1000204081)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question.  It is greatly appreciated!